# mkdir function not working in C

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2012, mkdir

I am trying to create a file in C by trying to execute the following code segment, but I am getting an "identifier "mkdir" is not defined". I am working on a Windows Machine using Visual Studio.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<sys/types.h>

#include<sys/stat.h>

    int main()

          {

   char newTempFolderName[50];

  int a = mkdir("./newTempFolderName", 0700);

    return 0;

          }
```

Comment: It is working in ubuntu. In your program what is need of character array.. Because you are not used array.If want to create directory for array content, initialize or scan the array first,then use array in 'mkdir' system call like 'mkdir(newTempFolderName,07000).

Comment: For future reference, a simple search of `mkdir` on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com) comes up with [mkdir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235326.aspx)

Comment: @PaulR: last time I checked, mkdir wasn't in the C standard?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I'm not sure about C, but it's part of POSIX.

Comment: @PaulR: sure, but POSIX is a UNIX standard.  Calling Windows "non-standard" because it doesn't implement POSIX is like calling Java non-standard because it doesn't implement C11. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: OK - I admit it - I was being a little wasp-ish about Windows due to personal prejudice. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use WinApi's [CreateDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx) function or use `_mkdir()` (notice the underscore sign).

Example of CreateDirectory() - you need to include windows.h header file:

```
#include<windows.h>

int main() {
   CreateDirectory ("C:\\test", NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
 #if defined(_WIN32)
    _mkdir("./newTempFolderName");
     #else 
    mkdir("./newTempFolderName", 0700); 
     #endif
```

Comment: My problem has been solved by applying the above code. Thank You.